# How to figure out what's passing arguments to an Angular class constructor?

Tags: angular

I'm quite new to Angular, and bits and pieces of it are making sense, but I'm working on an existing project and don't even know how to Google this question.

If I see this code in my project:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  title: Title = {text: 'Messages', small: '', icon: 'messages'};
  private messages: Message[] = [];
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService,
              private playerService: PlayerService,
              private userService: UserService) { }
```

I can see that 3 services are being passed to `constructor()`. But what I haven't been able to find is, where are they being passed FROM? If I just make up a new argument to `constructor()`, it throws an error and tells me it can't resolve all parameters. So there must be a place where these parameters are being defined/passed in, but I can't locate it.

Sorry for the noob question; not sure what to search for (and this class doesn't use `@Injectable`).

Comment: Something to start with: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection. There is a lot involved with understanding dependency injection, so prepare to be whelmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are passed by Angular's Dependency Injection Mechanism to the constructor. You might want to learn more about Angular's Dependency Injection Mechanism.

Every class based building block in Angular might depend on something to get itself created. That's what is passed to the constructor.

Now before you pass anything to the `constructor`, you should make sure that Angular knows about it for that particular module.

To let it know about something(component, pipe, directive, service) etc, we generally add directives, components, and pipes to the `declarations` array of the `NgModule`. And for letting it know about services, we add them to the `providers` array of the `NgModule` decorator.

So in your case, you'll have to import `MessageService`, `PlayerService`, and `UserService` from their respective locations, and then you'll have to add them, to the `providers` array of the module that you're planning on using them in.

Hope this makes a little bit of sense now. You might want to learn more about it. Here's a [talk by Pascal Precht](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZefFBqBncOM) to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I have much to learn and I will watch that video. In the meantime. I do see `MessageService`, etc. in my component's `import{}` statement, but they are not in `providers` or `directives`, etc. But they still work. How could that be?

Comment: Please consider taking a course on Angular or reading about its basics first. It will give you a better understanding of the framework as a whole. And that would also automatically answer most of your questions for you.